# mysql convert string to time format wheb query from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Having a field storing time as varchar EX: `06:30 AM`. I need a select query from this field and convert to number `6.30` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIME_FORMAT()` for this

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT( column_name, '%H.%i' ) AS time from table_name;
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%h:%i %p'),'%H.%i') from table_name;
```

Comment: can you convert your column type to time??

Comment: can not coz i need store string

Answer (score 0):

convert the string using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date('g.i',strtotime('06:30 AM'));
```

outputs `6.30`

```
g => 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros    1 through 12
i => Minutes with leading zeros 00 to 59
```

Comment: can i select `min max` of this field ?